# Возможно ли получить доступ к элементу массива в get{}?

Tags: c#, get

Вот часть кода:

```
[SerializeField]
BoxCollider[] myBoxColliders;

public Vector3[] H_Pos
{ 
    get
    { 
        return myTransform.TransformPoint (myBoxColliders[i].center);
    }
}
```

Нужно в H_Pos получить доступ к соответствующему myBoxColliders.

Например, нужно чтобы H_Pos[5] возвращал значение из myBoxColliders[5].

Такое возможно сделать?

Comment: Вопрос очень прост или это невозможно сделать? Я новичок в C#, не могу найти информацию о том как такое сделать. В сети попадаются примеры с this, но у меня они почему-то не работают.

Comment: Если вам нужно что-то получить на основании какого-то аргумента, в вашем случае `myBoxColliders[i]`, то здесь напрашивается использование метода, а не свойства, не так ли?

Comment: В общем-то у меня реализовано пока именно так, но в сети я часто натыкался на возможность использования свойства. Для такого простого действия (получение значения), как мне кажется, наиболее логично использовать свойство т.к. я не произвожу в нем каких-то операций, которые обычно осуществляются в методах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [индексатор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6x16t2tx(v=vs.120)):

```
public Vector3 this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        return myTransform.TransformPoint(myBoxColliders[index].center);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, ваш класс *семантически* станет похож на коллекцию и обращаться к нему можно будет как к массиву:

```
var indexier = new Indexier();
Vector3 vector = indexier[5];
```

Но, если вы не разрабатываете *коллекцию*, то лучше выразить мысль при помощи метода:

```
public Vector3 GetByIndex(int index) 
{
    ...
}
```